# Can I get the choices in a symfony2 ChoiceType from a Choice Assert of the Entity?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I often have Symfony form fields of the ChoiceType type, corresponding to Entity-object-fields with a Choice Assert defining its valid choices. Like this example:

in the entity class:

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="myField", type="string", length=10, nullable=false)
 * @Assert\NotNull()
 * @Assert\Choice(choices={"Choice A", "Choice B", "Choice C"})
 */
private $myField;
```

and in the form class:

```
$builder->add('myField', ChoiceType::class, array(
    'choices' => array(
        'Choice A' => 'Choice A',
        'Choice B' => 'Choice B',
        'Choice C' => 'Choice C',
    ),
    'expanded' => true,
    'multiple' => false,
))
```

From time to time, those choices change and I have to sync that change within the entity class and all form classes referring to it.

### The question

The question is: Is there a way for the forms to take over the choices already defined in the entity class? Or another way to store the choices only once?

### Update: My solution

I implemented it like I mentioned in [my comment on Hakims answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35405668/can-i-get-the-choices-in-a-symfony2-choicetype-from-a-choice-assert-of-the-entit#comment58722193_35407138):

```
class MyEntity
{
    const VALID_VALUES_AS_FORM_CHOICES = true;
    const VALID_VALUES_AS_HASH = true;
    const VALID_VALUES_AS_LIST = false;

    const VALID_EXAMPLE_PROPERTY_VALUES = [
        'entities.MyEntity.exampleProperty.values.what' => 'what',
        'entities.MyEntity.exampleProperty.values.ever' => 'ever',
    ];

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="example_property", type="string", length=10, nullable=true, options={"default" : "what"})
     * @Assert\Choice(callback = "getValidExamplePropertyValues", message = "{{ value }} is not a valid value.")
     */
    private $exampleProperty;

    /**
     * Gets a list (default for use within Assert\Choice(callback="getValidExamplePropertyValues")
     * or a hash (for use in a ChoiceType form field)
     * of the valid values for the type property
     *
     * @param  bool  $asFormChoices  optional set to self::VALID_VALUES_AS_FORM_CHOICES to get a hash with values also as keys, defaults to self::VALID_VALUES_AS_LIST
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getValidExamplePropertyValues($asFormChoices = self::VALID_VALUES_AS_LIST)
    {
        return $asFormChoices ? self::VALID_EXAMPLE_PROPERTY_VALUES : array_values(self::VALID_EXAMPLE_PROPERTY_VALUES);
    }

    // other code
}
```

And within the form builder:

```
$builder->add('exampleProperty', \Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType::class, [
    'choices' => MyEntity::getValidExamplePropertyValues(MyEntity::VALID_VALUES_AS_FORM_CHOICES),
]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Choice.html#supplying-the-choices-with-a-callback-function

Creating an external class to handle your choices.

Comment: This sounds like a fairly elegant solution. Such a callback can also be called from the form builder.

Comment: I didn't try it, but sounds okay. I hoped that there is a built in way to get the choices from the Model into the form, like the type guessing. Another way is my own solution using getPropertyMetadata().

Comment: Works great. I now have a static method in the Entity returning the valid choices and in the form, I call it twice within array_combine to have an array with identical keys and values: `'choices' => array_combine(MyEntity::getValidChoicesForMyField(), MyEntity::getValidChoicesForMyField())`

Answer (score 0):

I usually create a Type class where i store my choices array. For example class with name myFieldType. I store there protected array with types, and getters for whole array or one element.

```
class myFieldType
{
 protected $myField = [
   'Choice A' => 'Choice A',
   'Choice B' => 'Choice B',
   'Choice C' => 'Choice C',
]

public function getType()
{
 return $this->myField
}
```

You can also create other getters, like for label or whatever.

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers my question. How does this information get from the Type class to the validation process of the entity?

Comment: Thats the answer for second part of your question :)

Answer (score 0):

To give a possible solution by myself: One could read the Metadata from the validation service, e.g. in a controller:

```
foreach($this->get('validator')
    ->getMetadataFor(myClass::class)
    ->getPropertyMetadata('myField')[0]->constraints as $constraint) {
    if (is_a($constraint, Choice::class)) {
        dump($constraint->choices);
        break;
    }
}
```

Et voilà, we have an array of the choices defined in the validation-annotation of the entity. This could be abstracted to be used in the form definitions, but this appeals a bit indirect to me. My question was more of the type "is there an intended way to sync the choices between the entity class an its forms?"

Comment: I prefer my other solution over this one, see the updated question.